# SQL query on column name ranges

Tags: sql, range

In a table I have columns that are the years 2014 through 2050.  If I want to write a query that will return the columns between a range based on parameter is this possible?  It becomes more tricky because in order for it to accept the column names as numbers they are stored as strings so they have to be cast before a comparison.  Tenor_End and Tenor_Start are ints (2014, 2015 ... 2050)

```
Select *
From MMD_Scale
WHERE (@Tenor_End   IS NULL and CAST(c.Name AS INT) >= @Tenor_Start) OR
      (@Tenor_Start IS NULL and CAST(c.Name AS INT) <= @Tenor_End) OR
      (@Tenor_Start IS NOT NULL AND @Tenor_End IS NOT NULL 
         AND CAST(c.Name AS INT) >= @Tenor_Start 
         AND CAST(c.Name AS INT) <= @Tenor_End) OR
      (@Tenor_Start IS NULL 
         AND @Tenor_End IS NULL 
         AND CAST(c.Name AS INT) IS NOT NULL)
```

This is what I cobbled together from online sources but c.Name is not a built in to reference column names. I also tried a similar logic after the select to no avail.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Microsoft SQL query being run in SSRS.  The table looks like

```
Date     | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
8/2/2013 | .1   | .9   |  1.7 |  2.0 | 2.5  |  1.1 | .1   |
8/6/2013 | .6   | 1.2  |  2.2 |  1.2 | 3.2  |  1.9 | .8   |
```

And I would want to display all the rows but a range of columns i.e. between 2014 and 2017

Comment: Which SQL version (looks like Microsoft SQL).   You most likely will need to use dynamic SQL

Comment: Can you describe the table set up? Perhaps provide a sample of the table with some data? Let's start by keeping the ranges short.

Comment: Having a column for each year may be a sign that your schema could use some work.  Are you sure you can't move that data into a different `Year` table?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use some dynamic sql e.g.

```
DECLARE @Tenor_Start    VARCHAR(100)='Col2014';
DECLARE @Tenor_End      VARCHAR(100)='Col2015';

DECLARE @query  NVARCHAR(MAX)=
'
    SELECT
     *
    FROM MMD_Scale
    WHERE '+@Tenor_Start+' IS NULL
    AND '+@Tenor_End+' IS NULL';

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

or

```
EXEC (@query);
```